# Angular 2+ Front End Authentication

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt

In an Angular 2 app, I'm using JWT to authenticate the user. The token is returned to the client and then stored in localStorage.

I want to protect certain Angular routes so that only logged in users can access them.

Until now, when the token gets returned I was setting a variable `isAuthenticated` in config service, and using this to decide whether a user could navigate to protected routes or not. But this variable of course doesn't persist after a refresh of the page. So I've removed `isAuthenticated`, and am instead checking to see if the token exists (and hasn't expired), before deciding whether to allow the user to access protected routes.

I'm using Angular's Router Module to handle the routing, and the canActivate hook to see whether a user is authenticated / logged in.

app.module:

```
{ path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
// ... other routes
```

then AuthGuard (Basically if a token exists and it hasn't expired, activate the route):

```
canActivate() {
  let base64Url = localStorage.getItem('token').split('.')[1];
  let base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
  let token = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));
  let now = new Date().getTime();
  return (localStorage.getItem('token') && token.exp > now) ? true : false;
}
```

My issue is, I guess it would be trivial to fake the JWT token to gain access to the Angular routes, but I don't want to make an API call just because a user has navigated to another page. So is this implementation the best way to go? Necessary API calls (GETs, POSTs, PUTs, DELETEs etc) will still go through the authorisation process, so it's only the frontend routes which are vulnerable.

Is this normal practice, or is there another approach I should be using? I definitely don't want to be re-inventing the wheel with site security.

Comment: You have to send the token back to the backend/API on each request and let this layer check if it's a valid token or not. You can use http interceptors to handle this: https://medium.com/tableless/angular-4-and-ionic-3-add-custom-headers-to-http-requests-11aaf93798d9

Comment: can you share your code snippets or just share plunker link